# Bash: Allow parentheses in command arguments (i.e. prevent "unexpected token '(' ")

Tags: bash, quoting

I am frequently using a command line program that I provide with arguments that contain parentheses. For simplicity, let's say I'm writing

`echo 'bar(1,3)'`

I would like to omit the quotes. However, if I do that I get `syntax errror near unexpected token '('`. I guess this is related to subshells. I am willing to disable those, if that's the only way. (though a subshell cannot be started if it is not at the beginning of the command anyway, so they are no reason to forbid parentheses in the arguments, as far as I can tell)

Comment: Try `echo bar\(1,3\)`

Comment: Why do you want to omit the quotes?

Comment: You can not "disable subshells".

Comment: @Flimm I want to omit the quotes out of laziness and because I often forget them and then have to to even more typing

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`(` and `)` are special token characters in the syntax of `bash` that are used in a number of operators including:

- `(...)` subshell construct
- `func() compound-command` function definitions
- `$(...)` command substitution
- `<(...)`, `>(...)` process substitution
- `((...))` arithmetic evaluation construct
- `$((...))` arithmetic expansion
- `a=(...)`, `a+=(...)` array assignment operators
- `@(...)`, `+(...)`, `*(...)`, `?(...)` glob operators (with extglob)
- `[[ (a && b) || (c && d) ]]` grouping conditional expression operators
- `[[ ... =~ ...(...)... ]]` regexp operator.

`echo a=(b)` is a syntax error, but not `export a=(b)`.

`echo a)` is a syntax error, unless there was an opening `(` in the previous lines part of one of the constructs above.

While it may be possible to write a readline hook that adds quotes where needed around `(`, `)` to avoid a syntax error, it would be considerable effort as it would mean doing a full parsing of the shell syntax.

A better approach may be to use a shortcut  that quotes the current word when you realise too late that it contains characters special to the shell.

With `zsh` (assuming `emacs` mode):

```
bindkey -s '\e#' '\C@\eb\Cx\Cx\e"'
```

To have <kbd>Alt+#</kbd> quote the current *word*.

Or  an approximation with `bash` (also assuming `emacs` mode):

```
bind "\"\e#\": \"'\e \eb'\C-X\C-X\""
```

Comment: I agree with your better approach. Thanks for the bash update. If anyone else needs this but has vi-mode enabled as I do, I modified this to `bind "\"\e#\": \"'\eF a'"`. This puts quotes around the current argument as defined by the cursor until the closest space character before it.

Comment: To the maintainers of this site, I suggest that you have a repository of such answers, so that they can be straightway accessed later on.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a bad idea (see the comments), but I had the same problem and I solved it by making
a function that changes `[` into `(` and `]` into `)` before using it:

```
echo2() {
    expression=$(echo $@ | tr '[]' '()')
    echo "$expression"
}
```

input:

```
echo2 bar[1,3]
```

result:

```
bar(1,3)
```

I don't know if the `[` and `]` are treated specially by the shell. But if
you're ok with using them in place of `(` and `)` for your function maybe this
a solution for you.

Comment: I think when the OP writes "I am frequently using a command line program [...]. For simplicity, let's say I'm writing `echo 'bar(1,3)'`", it really means the program is not (or at least not necessarily) `echo`.

Comment: `[` is treated specially since it introduces a globbing pattern.  Your string `bar[1,3]` is a globbing pattern that matches the three filenames `bar1`, `bar,`, and `bar3`. The pattern would be replaced by these names if the existed in the current directory, or the pattern may be removed completely if the `nullglob` shell option is set, or it may generate a fatal error if the `failglob` shell option is set.

Comment: Also note that swapping `()` with `[]` is more efficiently done with `tr '()' '[]'`, and that `echo $@` will have issues if any argument is a pattern or contains whitespace, or starts with a string that is an option to `echo`, or contains backslashes in certain constellations (e.g. `\n`).

Comment: @they Thanks for these comments - I didn't know that the square brackets could be used in this way. I guess it's a bad idea to do this...